# How to check a struct is not null in Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want to query JSON data with Redshift Spectrum to find out if a field in the JSON exists.

So for example. Given the data:

```
{ "field1" : { "one" : 1, "two" : 2}, "field2" : true }
{ "field2" : false }
```

And given I have defined my table as:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow_sample AS (
  field1 struct<
    one:varchar,
    two:varchar
  >,
  field2 boolean
)
```

I want to be able to query it with something like:

```
SELECT field2 FROM stackoverflow_sample WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL;
```

And get the result:

```
TRUE
```

However I keep getting the error `column field1 does not exist`

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: One approach can be to include the list of fields in the condition   "field1.one IS NOT NULL and field1.two IS NOT NULL"

Comment: That might work in some cases, but with that approach one cannot distinguish absent values from present values with all its members at `null`. For example, `{ "field1" : { "one" : null, "two" : null}, "field2" : true }` is indistinguishable from `{ "field1" : null, "field2" : true }` and from `{ "field2" : true }` (which have different meanings in my use case)